# I'd like to know about Tahajjud Prayer in detail

Tags: tahajjud

I'd like to know about Tahajjud Prayer in detail. If there is any specific rules, what Allah's sayings about Tahajjud Prayer in Quran  and benefits of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

walecum assalam,

Tahajjud is very important prayer from islamic point of view. one of best ways to ask forgiveness and ask for blessing of Allah.

Allah says in Quran about tahajjud prayer:

> Establish prayer at the decline of the sun [from its meridian] until
>   the darkness of the night and [also] the Qur’an of dawn. Indeed, the
>   recitation of dawn is ever witnessed.And from [part of] the night,
>   pray with it as additional [worship] for you; it is expected that your
>   Lord will resurrect you to a praised station.” (Surah Isra, 17:78-79).

Also

> {And they who pass the night prostrating themselves before their Lord
>   and standing.} (Al-Furqan 25:64)

and some hadith:

> Narrated ‘Aisha: Allah’s Apostle(SAW) used to offer eleven Rakat and
>   that was his prayer. He used to prolong the prostration to such an
>   extent that one could recite fifty verses (of the Quran) before he
>   would lift his head. He used to pray two Rakat (Sunna) before the Fajr
>   prayer and then used to lie down on his right side till the call-maker
>   came and informed him about the prayer.  [Bukhari]

and

> Abd Allah ibn Salam (Allah be pleased with him) reports that the
>   Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace be upon him, his family, and
>   companions) said, “O people! Spread the salams, feed others, maintain
>   family ties, and pray at night when others sleep and you will enter
>   Heaven safely.”[Tirmidhi, Hakim]
>
> Narrated Al-Mughira: The Prophet(SAW) used to stand (in the prayer) or
>   pray till both his feet or legs swelled. He was asked why (he offered
>   such an unbearable prayer) and he said, “should I not be a thankful
>   slave.” [Bukahri]
>
> Narrated Salim’s father: In the life-time of the Prophet(SAW)
>   whosoever saw a dream would narrate it to Allah’s Apostle(SAW). I had
>   a wish of seeing a dream to narrate it to Allah’s Apostle (p.b.u.h) I
>   was a grown up boy and used to sleep in the Mosque in the life-time of
>   the Prophet. I saw in the dream that two angels caught hold of me and
>   took me to the Fire which was built all round like a built well and
>   had two poles in it and the people in it were known to me. I started
>   saying, “I seek refuge with Allah from the Fire.” Then I met another
>   angel who told me not to be afraid. I narrated the dream to Hafsa who
>   told it to Allah’s Apostle(SAW). The Prophet(SAW) said, “Abdullah is a
>   good man. I wish he prayed Tahajjud.” After that ‘Abdullah (i.e.
>   Salim’s father) used to sleep but a little at night.  [Bukhari]

Answer (score 1):

> O you wrapped in garments (i.e. Prophet Muhammad SAW)!
>
> **Stand** (to pray) all night, except a little.
>
> Half of it, or a little less than that,
>
> Or a little more; and **recite the Quran** (aloud) in a slow, (pleasant tone and) style...
>
> ..Verily, the rising by night (for Tahajjud prayer) is very hard and most potent and good for governing (the soul), and most suitable for (understanding) the Word (of Allah).
>
> **Verily, there is for you by day prolonged occupation with ordinary duties**,
>
> And **remember the Name of your Lord and devote yourself to Him with a complete devotion.**
>
> (He Alone is) the Lord of the east and the west, La ilaha illa Huwa (none has the right to be worshipped but He). So take Him Alone as Wakil (Disposer of your affairs).
>
> Verily, your Lord knows that you do stand (to pray at night) a little less than two-thirds of the night, or half the night, or a third of the night, and so do a party of those with you, And Allah measures the night and the day. **He knows that you are unable to pray the whole night, so He has turned to you** (in mercy). So, recite you of the Quran as much as may be easy for you. He knows that there will be some among you sick, others travelling through the land, seeking of Allah's Bounty; yet others fighting in Allah's Cause. So recite as much of the Quran as may be easy (for you), and perform As-Salat (Iqamat-as-Salat) and give Zakat, and lend to Allah a goodly loan, and **whatever good you send before you for yourselves,** (i.e. Nawafil non-obligatory acts of worship: prayers, charity, fasting, Hajj and 'Umrah, etc.), **you will certainly find it with Allah, better and greater in reward. And seek Forgiveness of Allah. Verily, Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most-Merciful.**

(Qur'an 73:1-9 Surah Muzammil)

May the creator guide us all.